# SQL Server 2005 - Dynamic PIVOT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I require your kind help on a `PIVOT` query problem.
The scenario is I have a voting system.  Comprises of 3 tables.
Elections, Candidates, Votes.

The PIVOT relates to `PIVOTing` the Candidate names as Columns and having the VOTE data as the data.

So far I have attemped this and not got it to work, I've gotten into a muddle with it :(

```
CREATE TABLE  #MYELECTIONS (E_POSITION_CODE INT, E_POSITIONNAME VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (147,'MANAGER')
    INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (148,'CHEF')
    INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (149,'WAITER')

CREATE TABLE  #MYCANDIDATES (C_CANDIDATE_CODE INT, 
                          C_CANDIDATENAME VARCHAR (50), C_POSITION_CODE INT)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (100,'TOM CRUISE', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (101,'MICKY MOUSE', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (103,'DONALD DUCK', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (100,'TOM CRUISE', 148)

CREATE TABLE  #MYVOTES (V_POSITION_CODE INT, 
                        V_CANDIDATE_CODE INT, VOTINGPREFERENCE SMALLINT)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,103,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,1)

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName         AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @MyPositionCode     AS INT
SET @MyPositionCode = 147

DECLARE @MyOutput           AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
                + QUOTENAME(C_CANDIDATENAME)

FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT C_CANDIDATENAME 
    FROM #MYCANDIDATES 
    WHERE C_POSITION_CODE = @MyPositionCode 
    ORDER BY C_CANDIDATE_CODE) AS C_CANDIDATENAME


--Prepare the `PIVOT` query using the dynamic sql
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E_POSITIONNAME) AS Idnum,    
  E_POSITIONNAME AS [Position Name], ' + @ColumnName + '
  FROM  #MYVOTES 
  INNER JOIN #MYELECTIONS 
  ON (#MYVOTES.V_POSITION_CODE = #MYELECTIONS.E_POSITION_CODE)
    PIVOT(SUM(VOTINGPREFERENCE))
      FOR C_CANDIDATENAME IN (' + @ColumnName + ') AS PVTTable
  WHERE #MYELECTIONS.E_POSITION_CODE = 147'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql  @DynamicPivotQuery, 
                    @MyOutput = @MyOutput OUTPUT

SELECT @MyOutput

DROP TABLE #MYELECTIONS
DROP TABLE #MYCANDIDATES
DROP TABLE #MYVOTES
```

It has to be a dynamic `PIVOT` as the Candidate Names that I want to `Pivot` as Columns, could be dynamic depending on how many Candidates there are for an Election position.

The desired output for the above would be like this:-

Election @MyPositionCode = 147

```
Idnum   Position_Name   TOM CRUISE  MICKY MOUSE  DONALD DUCK...

1       MANAGER         4           2            1
```

Election @MyPositionCode = 148

```
Idnum   Position_Name   TOM CRUISE  MICKY MOUSE  DONALD DUCK...

1       CHEF            2           0            0
```

Comment: Have you written a static version of this first?  It's significantly easy to start with that, then convert to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi, I went for the dynamic to begin with, as I followed a dymanic pivot example, which I can't get to work.  I need help!

Comment: Try writing a static version first.

Comment: If you filter `E_POSITION_CODE` with 147 then how will u get the `CHEF` in ur expected output?

Comment: what do you get when you PRINT DynamicPivotQuery right before executing it?

Comment: If you wrote this staticly, then you'd know that your query syntax is wrong because you are referencing `C_CANDIDATENAME` in your query but it doesn't exist in any of the tables you are joining.

Comment: Yes Bluefeet.You are right. Even expected output is different from what he/she has given as values in tables. @bluefeet♦

Comment: I have amended the desired outcome, sorry about that. It's causing me a headache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @MyPositionCode     AS INT
SET @MyPositionCode = 147
```

Declare the variables for selecting dynamic columns

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName         AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + C_CANDIDATENAME + ']', '[' + C_CANDIDATENAME + ']')
               FROM    
               (
                    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT C_CANDIDATENAME 
                    FROM #MYCANDIDATES 
                    WHERE C_POSITION_CODE = @MyPositionCode 
                    ORDER BY C_CANDIDATE_CODE
                ) PV 
               ORDER BY C_CANDIDATENAME desc
```

If you want to replace `NULL` with zero

```
DECLARE @NulltoZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+C_CANDIDATENAME+'],0) AS ['+C_CANDIDATENAME+']' 
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT C_CANDIDATENAME 
    FROM #MYCANDIDATES 
    WHERE C_POSITION_CODE = @MyPositionCode 
    ORDER BY C_CANDIDATE_CODE
)TAB  
ORDER BY C_CANDIDATENAME desc FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Now pivot it dynamically. I have written the logic inside

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '-- You can apply ROW_NUMBER() here which is the data after pivot 
              SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E_POSITIONNAME) AS Idnum,
              ,E_POSITIONNAME,'+@NullToZeroCols+'  
              FROM 
             (           
                -- Select data before pivot      
                SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT ME.E_POSITIONNAME,MC.C_CANDIDATENAME,
                COUNT(MC.C_CANDIDATENAME) OVER(PARTITION BY ME.E_POSITIONNAME,MC.C_CANDIDATENAME) CNT
                FROM #MYELECTIONS ME
                JOIN #MYCANDIDATES MC ON ME.E_POSITION_CODE=MC.C_POSITION_CODE
                JOIN #MYVOTES MV ON MC.C_CANDIDATE_CODE=MV.V_CANDIDATE_CODE
                AND MV.V_POSITION_CODE=MC.C_POSITION_CODE
                WHERE MC.C_POSITION_CODE = ' + CAST(@MyPositionCode AS VARCHAR(30)) + '
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR C_CANDIDATENAME IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Click the below link. If the result is not auto-generated, press **RUN QUERY** button.

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/280398/pivot-query) to view  result**

Comment: Please reply for any clarifications or changes @user154550

Comment: I don't know who down voted for me. Since **SQL FIDDLE** have internal error, I cannot prove it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply, as it was end of the working day in the UK when I last replied.  Wasn't me who voted you down, I am testing your code now.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: I have updated with working SQL example. See the last part of the answer. @user154550

Comment: Thanks, that's works great! I couldn't have worked that out without some help, Cheers!